# SQL selection problems

Tags: sqlite

I am working with SQLite and I think I have a problem getting table ID, my table stores book categories, their images details here is a graphical representation of my table

`| mSubCategory_id | mCategory_id_FK | mSubCategory_description | mSubCategory_image|`

my problem is getting the ID field values, below is a query am using to match books in my sub Cateogory table with a certain Category, its working perfectly but I cannot seem to access value of id, I am getting the same value for `id` and `mSubCateogory_id` which in the actual sense is the value for `mSubCateogory_id` and not `id` below is the query am using:

```
    String sQuery = " SELECT "+mCategory_id+", "+mCategory_id_FK+", "+Constant.SUB_DESCRIPTION+
            ", "+mSubCategory_image+" FROM  "+CATEGORY_TABLE+
    " INNER JOIN "+SUB_CATEGORY_TABLE+" ON "+mCategory_id +" = " +mCategory_id_FK
   + " WHERE "+mCategory_id +" = ?";

    String[] args = new String[1];
    args[0] = String.valueOf(mtargetID);


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sQuery, args);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ExpandableCategoryItem mCateogory= new ExpandableCategoryItem();

            //I am getting the same value here whether I use 
            //getString(0) or getString(1)
            mCateogory.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            mCateogory.setmDescription(cursor.getString(2));
            mCateogory.setmCategoryImgPath(cursor.getString(3));

            mCategoryImgPost.add(mCateogoryPost);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String sQuery = " SELECT "+mCategory_id+", "+mCategory_id_FK+", "+Constant.SUB_DESCRIPTION+
 ", "+mSubCategory_image+" FROM  "+CATEGORY_TABLE+
        " INNER JOIN "+SUB_CATEGORY_TABLE+" ON "+mCategory_id +" = " +mCategory_id_FK
       + " WHERE "+mCategory_id +" = ?";
```

In the above query there are mCategory_id and mCategory_id_Fk columns which are probably the same. You need to replace either of them with with mSubCategory_id

Comment: great answer, I did not see that coming